# How to supply location services to diffent activities on Android

Tags: android, location

I am currently working on an Android app and I am new to the field.
I want to do the following:

Create a class that encapsulates the required features to let an activity know the users location and deliver a map to the activity

This should accomplish the following:

I have a class that connects to the location services to get information and other activities can use this class to get a map (fragment) along with other information (lat long etc) for programmatic use.

I cannot figure it out...I do not want my stuff to an Activity itself
But it seems as if the whole Google Location API of the Play services  relies on it being a FragmentActivity (whatever that is)

Any ideas?

PS: I need to maintain support for 2.3.3

**UPDATE**
I made it to implement a class extending SupportMapFragment (shortened), but I am having trouble with the error handling for the GMS. Works fine on my Galaxy Note 3 but the emulator has an older version of GMS which (due to currently crappy errorhandling) eventually leads to a NullPointer Exception:

```
public class LocationFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, 
LocationListener {

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);

        initilizeMap();
        configureLocationClient();

        locationManager = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Start with updates turned off
        updatesRequested = false;
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        locationClient = new LocationClient(activity.getBaseContext(), this, this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activity = getActivity();

        checkGooglePlayServices();
    }

private boolean checkGooglePlayServices() {
        // Check that Google Play services is available
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity.getBaseContext());
        // If Google Play services is available
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
            // In debug mode, log the status
            Log.d(TAG + ".servicesConnected()", "Google Play services is available.");
            // Continue
            return true;
        // Google Play services was not available for some reason
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG + ".servicesConnected()", "Google Play services is unavailable or outdated: " + resultCode);
            // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
            try {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, activity, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: GooglePlayServiceUtil: ", "" + e);
            }
            /**
            Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, activity, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

            // If Google Play services can provide an error dialog
            if (errorDialog != null) {
                // Create a new DialogFragment for the error dialog
                ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
                // Set the dialog in the DialogFragment
                errorFragment.setDialog(errorDialog);
                // Show the error dialog in the DialogFragment
                errorFragment.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(),"Location Updates");
            }*/

            return false;
        }
    }
```

The corresponding Activity is:

```
public class LocationTest extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
    private static final String TAG = LocationTest.class.getSimpleName();

    private int count = 0;

    private TextView lat;
    private TextView lng;
    private TextView quality;
    private TextView conState;
    private TextView refreshCount;
    private TextView distance;
    private LocationFragment locFrag;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.locationtest);

        FragmentManager fManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        locFrag = new LocationFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.map, locFrag);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();

        locFrag.setGoal(Double.valueOf(8.83749747285), Double.valueOf(53.0663656578));

        lat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.curLat);
        lng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.curLng);
        quality = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.curQuality);
        conState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.conState);
        refreshCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);
        distance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance);
    }

    public void refreshLocation(View v) {
        locFrag.refreshLocation(v);
    }
    public void toggleUpdates(View v) {
        locFrag.toggleUpdates(v);

    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)  {
        // Let the location parent know about the location change
//      super.onLocationChanged(location);
        count++;
        lat.setText(Double.toString(locFrag.getCurrentLatitude()));
        lng.setText(Double.toString(locFrag.getCurrentLongitude())); 
        quality.setText(Float.toString(locFrag.getAccuracy()));
        conState.setText(Boolean.toString(locFrag.isConnected()));
        refreshCount.setText(Integer.toString(count));
        distance.setText(Float.toString(locFrag.getDistance()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume()");
    }
}
```

I wonder if it is possible to get the ErrorDialog suggested by google to work from that SupportMapFragment to be able to handle the error or else stop the inflation of the fragment and return to the previous activity

any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in present class which is capturing the location

**currentLocation** is the location Object

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,target.class)
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putParcelable("Location", currentLocation);
i.putExtra("Location", b);
startActivity(i);
```

**Receive Activity code:**

```
b = getArguments();
Location location = b.getParcelable("Location");
```

By this way you can pass the location.I think it may be useful to you.